# UML plugin for Python in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse

I want to generate UML class diagrams for the python project developed in Eclipse. I tried to use PyUML but it did not work. The installation failed. Are there any other plugins that I can use? I need to add UML class diagrams in my project report. Please let me know if there are suitable plugins available which is working. I have PyDev already installed and the project is created using PyDev.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry that I can't help you with this great question(+1 and favourite), but I hope that you are aware of the free [Plant UML](http://plantuml.com/) tool, which you can use stand-alone if you don't find an Eclipse Plug in.   Hint, start by looking at https://marketplace.eclipse.org/taxonomy/term/19%2C31 and, if you do find something, please post about it here, to help others in future. Thanks